# Adding in javascript on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When someone clicks my price up button, I want the price to increase by .1 in the #priceInput box. This is just not working though.. what am I doing wrong?

```
$("#priceUp").click(function(){ 
    var xyz = parseInt($("#priceInput").val());
    xyz=(xyz+.1);
    $("#priceInput").val(xyz);
});
```

Comment: elaborate on "just not working"

Comment: What's the outcome? is the value changing? nothing happens? did you make sure the event fires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `parseFloat`, not `parseInt` since you're increasing the price by `0.1`. Also, you need to make sure that the value of `#priceInput` is a number:

```
$("#priceUp").click(function() {
    var xyz = parseFloat($("#priceInput").val() || 0);
    xyz = (xyz + .1);
    $("#priceInput").val(xyz);
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MHQPc/).

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to parse a decimal number to an integer, so your solution can't work because the mathematic evaluator round your number. 
If you run parseInt(0.1), the result is 0.

So, use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.

You need also a little trick to avoid the '0.30000000000000004' "bug" (it's not really a bug).
Solution here : http://jsfiddle.net/erLqa/

Comment: Your answer tells OP how to fix it, not what he is doing wrong.

Comment: I've added a little explanation.

Answer (score 4):

It may not work because you add `0.1`, but later you use a `parseInt`. Use `parseFloat` instead of `parseInt`.